# Heroku not detecting language

Tags: python, heroku

I am trying to push a VERY simple Flask app to Heroku, and get the following :

```
No default language could be detected for this app.
remote:             HINT: This occurs when Heroku cannot detect the buildpack to use for this application automatically.
remote:             See https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks
```

I have deployed a few before, and never encountered this problem.

I tried specifying the official Heroku/Python buildpack, but got a different error, so I reverted (actually, deleted and recreated the app through Heroku's interface).

Here is the tree from my app's directory:

```
├── Pipfile
├── Pipfile.lock
├── Procfile
├── runtime.txt
└── simple_app
    ├── app.py
    ├── .env
    └── __init__.py
```

Comment: You don't have a setup.py or requirements.txt: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-support#recognizing-a-python-app

Comment: Based on your comment, I added a requirements.txt file to the topmost dir.  No joy.  Do I need ALSO a setup.py file?  I've never used one before.

Comment: It says "or", so one or the other should work. If you're deploying via git is that file in the commit?

Comment: Many people use "you don't have a gun or a knife" to mean "you have neither a gun nor a knife". I created, added, committed, and pushed.

Comment: If someone asks you if you have a gun or a knife, don't be surprised if they're pretty upset when it turns out you said no because you only had one of them.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a 'package.json' file in the main folder of your project

```
{
  "engines": {
    "yourlenguage": "yourversion"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "python yourfile / node yourfile / ..."
  }
}
```

Comment: Why would you put an NPM package file in a Python project?

Comment: I have never needed a package.json file before.

Comment: that is because your app was autodetecting the language

Comment: But a package.json activates the *Node* buildpack, totally the wrong language: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-support#activation

Comment: i think you must do the same with python

Comment: I do not think it is required with python.  Other mechanisms are used.  I've published Flask apps to Heroku without any package.json file.

Comment: Per the page

https://help.heroku.com/1MC2J0GF/why-does-my-app-fail-to-detect-a-buildpack

This should inform Heroku that the app is a Python app.

What can I do to ensure that Heroku detects that the app is Python?